# I am trying to overlap 2 images olbique over eachother HTML

Tags: html, css

I've been searching around the internet for a while but i can't quite find a solution to what i want. I want 2 images to go oblique over eachother like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PH2o.png)

Comment: Best solution to that would be to edit the images , crop them the way you want and merge them into one image. That way you would only have to load one instead of two

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clip-path` property to have same effect

```css
.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}
.img1 {
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 100%);
}
.img2 {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
  position:relative;
  left:-202px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://pixy.org/src/477/4774988.jpg" class="img1 img">
<img src="https://pixy.org/src/480/4800346.jpg" class="img2 img">
```